# How to setup Pixi JS bones for custom shape?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I'm gonna animate a 2D character (filled shape drawn on HTML5 canvas using several closed Bezier curves) with bones or something like but can't find a simple way to do it.

The example [Textured Mesh - Basic](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/mesh-and-shaders/textured-mesh-basic.js) is closest to my issue but it shows the animation of PNG image.
May be I should use another library for this idea?